# The frame is getting repeated in Classic ASP application

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vb6

I am supporting an old classic asp application which is built on VB6.The problem is when I click the **submit for approval** button in the below[image]

The frame is getting repeated as below...
[image]

But when I click on any option of leftmost menulist(For ex: Leave and Attendance Management in the left most menu list) or when I refresh the whole page, The page is displayed finely as below.

[image]

As the code is in classic ASP I was unable to debug the code.I am attaching the .asp code of **Leave application form** page (i.e., the  code of first screen shot ) below.

Due to lack of space I am giving you a shared link : [Click here...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Q64fahdsDpYUstcVgyWmwtaE0/view?usp=sharing)
Code is bit big.Kindly help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshots and the code it looks like the **leave application form** is being loaded within an iframe on the page of your first screenshot, so when you submit you are loading the posted page into the same iframe. The code (in your shared link) at line 50 seems to target one frame over another depending on a querystring. I would debug the parent page to ensure you have the correct name or target _top to ensure the posted page takes over the whole screen

Comment: Thank you very much man....